# Laravel multiple select array validation always give error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using multiple select in my form, facing problem with its form validation, i am using multiple select field name as array if i give same name for validation rule its work great, but keep giving validation error on selected options also. here is my html code and validation rule.

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="skills[]" class="form-control">
```

validation rule

```
'skills[]' => 'required'
```

if i use field name without [] or skills.* validation not working for this field, guide me where i am doing something wrong. I am using laravel 5.7 for my project.

Comment: You have to use it without `[]`

Comment: And hello btw :P studied at SAE together lol :D

Comment: @emotality yes i remember you

Comment: @devk i have to use without [] in validation rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `select` looks like this for example:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="skills" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Skills</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select multiple name="skills[]" id="skills" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('skills') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" required>
            <option value="ios">iOS</option>
            <option value="php">PHP</option>
            <option value="laravel">Laravel</option>
        </select>
        @if($errors->has('skills'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('skills') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Create a custom request:

```
$ php artisan make:request ExampleRequest
```

`ExampleRequest` validation would look like this:

```php
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'skills' => 'required|array',
    ];
}
```

Then just grab the validated data from your `$request` directly

```php
public function submitForm(ExampleRequest $request)
{
    // at this point, validation already passed
    // if validation failed, you would be back at form with errors
    $skills = request('skills');
    // or
    $skills = $request->skills;

    dd($skills);
}
```

Custom requests are being validated first before even hitting your controller method.

Comment: Why `required` needs `form-control`?

Comment: Yes created a new project with a new request, ran all scenarios and its working 100%. :) Show your whole validation maybe you’re doing something wrong?

Comment: Updated the answer. :)

Comment: yes its working fine, in my formbuilder for getting errors i was using field name with [] that's why it was now showing error. thanks for help

Comment: No problem, keep well! :)